# java ByteBuffer getInt in python?

Tags: java, python, byte

```java
byte[] obyteArray = new byte[4];
String str = "testing";
try{
    obyteArray = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
}catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){    
}
int vi1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(obyteArray).getInt();
System.out.println(vi1);
```

returns 1952805748

however in py

```py
elements = b"testing"
values = bytearray(elements)
print(int.from_bytes(values, 'big'))
```

returns 32762643847147111

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. I've explained why you don't get the same results in my answer, but if you want more help we need to know the problem you're trying to solve.  Java and Python are very different languages. For example, Python supports arbitrary precision integers, while Java requires that you use `BigInteger` for that.

Comment: Got it to work with info from your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    byte[] obyteArray = new byte[4];
    String str = "testing";
    try{
        obyteArray = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

After the statement above the original `oByteArray` is discarded, and `oByteArray` is a reference to a different 7 byte array.

```
    }catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){    
    }
    int vi1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(obyteArray).getInt();
```

`vi1` is now the first 4 bytes (`'test'`) reinterpreted as an `int`.

```
    System.out.println(vi1);
```

which is why the results differ.